# C# - how to make a request to Google Developer API

Tags: c#, google-api, google-oauth

I'm trying to make a get request to the Google Developer API to see a set of reviews. I can see from Google's documentation that the get request I need to make is: `https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/your_package_name/reviews?
access_token=your_auth_token`

When attempting to set up the API access (following Google's Getting Started guide) I was given a JSON certificate that contained the following JSON (I have removed the private information):

```
  "type": "",
  "project_id": "",
  "private_key_id": "",
  "private_key": "",
  "client_email": "",
  "client_id": "",
  "auth_uri": "",
  "token_uri": "",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "",
  "client_x509_cert_url": ""
}
```

Where can I find the auth token needed for the Get request? I have tried looking at lots of the OAuth documentation as well as other answers on here but am still confused as to what the exact steps actually are to get what I want? I am not experienced with this sort of thing and would appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction in terms of the steps I actually need to take to get from the JSON Certificate to the GET request above? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Google documentation:

> 1. Go to the APIs Console and log in with your Google Play Console account.
> 2. Select Create project.
> 3. Go to Services in the left-hand navigation panel.
> 4. Turn the Google Play Android Developer API on.
> 5. Accept the Terms of Service.
> 6. Go to API Access in the left-hand navigation panel.
> 7. Select Create an OAuth 2.0 client ID. On the first
>      page, you will need to fill in the product name, but a logo is not
>      required. Note that your end users will not see the product name. On
>      the second page, select web application and set the redirect URI and
>      Javascript origins. Both of these settings can be changed later.
> 8. Select Create client ID.

[Source](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/authorization)

Comment: I already have the client ID @JorgeSantiago - it's in the JSON I posted

Comment: Have you followed the subsequent steps? That may be what you're looking for then